# How can I Integrate TFS 2017 and CRM 2013?

Tags: tfs, dynamics-crm, integration, dynamics-crm-2013

Is there any way to integrate TFS and CRM together without use the API?

Is there some configurable TFS tool that can help me to do it?

Comment: Can you be more clear about what you are trying to achieve. You can integrate Dynamics AX with TFVC.

Comment: Yes, I need be able to see from TFS the different cases present in the CRM and from the CRM the work item assigned to each case.

Comment: OK, so you are talking out API integration between CRM & TFS.

Comment: I think so, this is the first time that I'm trying to do it and I didn't really find any useful documentation so I've not idea from where start and how to do it, I found documentation of how integrate TFS and Share-Point but anything regarding TFS and CRM, just not free software that integrate everything for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know, there is no such free tool to integrate TFS and CRM. You would need to use TFS API and CRM api to create your own:

TFS API: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/overview

CRM API: https://developers.cloud-elements.com/docs/elements/dynamicscrm/index.html

Comment: Is there another way to archive my goal? I mean is there a way to import external data source or to connect TFS directly to CRM DB?

Comment: Do you mean you want to import CRM data to TFS work item? You may try to add bulk work items with Excel, check: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel

Comment: Do you think I can use this? SSIS Integration Toolkit for Microsoft Dynamics